# A5/1 Formula Question's

Tags: stream-cipher

So before I start I'm learning how this algorithm still works so my first question is for the x,y, and z *steps* (of getting the keystream I believe). The formula is *t* = *y* 20 XOR *y* 21 for y. There is one for *x* which I believe is the XOR of 13,16,17, and 18. Then *z* is the XOR of 7,20,21, and 22. Now my question is do these formulas ever change or are they always like this. Also later on in the keystream is *s* = *x* 18 XOR *y* 21 XOR *z* 22 always the same formula or does this change depending of the plaintext size? Finally is major also *m* = *maj* (*x* 18, *y* 10, *z* 10) every time?

Side Questions I also noticed while solving this?

- When you do the actual bit shift does the last variable like *x* 22 disappear?
- If the s formula was to be solved with *s* = 0 XOR 1 XOR 1 would the correct logic be 0 XOR 1 = 1 so then 1 XOR 1 = 0 so *s* = 0?

Comment: Did you start reading Wikipedia page about [A5/1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A5/1)?

Comment: Guess not, thanks. Out of curiosity though do you know what tapped bits mean.

Comment: Then, start reading [LFSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register) from Wikipedia. A5/1 constructed with 3 LFSR which are not regularly clocked.